# Firebase RecyclerView UI not showing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have been trying to implement `firebase ui` in my app with `recyclerview`. I have items on my firebase database which i want to with `firebase ui recycler view`. So far, i think i have done everything right, however, when i run my app it still shows blank. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class UsersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private Query query;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_users);
        query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions <Users> firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Users>()
                .setQuery(query, Users.class).build();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions){

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_single_layout, parent,false);
                return new UsersViewHolder(mView);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Users model) {
                holder.setName(model.getName());

            }
        };
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
    public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
View mView;
        UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }
        public void setName (String name){
            TextView mName = mView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            mName.setText(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following:

> The `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` uses an event listener to monitor changes to the Firebase query. To begin listening for data, call the `startListening()` method. You may want to call this in your `onStart()` method. Make sure you have finished any authentication necessary to read the data before calling `startListening()` or your query will fail.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
 }
```

more info here:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database